# Three.js – Applying texture to Collada mesh yields unexpected result

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

Following the [Three.js ColladaLoader example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html), I've exported a Cinema4D soda 
can model ([consisting of 4 meshes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGXEW.png)) to a .dae file. One of the meshes, the body of the can, I want to add a texture to.

In Cinema4D I've already made [a texture](https://www.ufomeldpunt.nl/so/wrapper.png) based on a UV map of the mesh (spherical). However, when I try to apply the texture to the mesh, it simply shows a solid white fill. I've added the entire code in [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/oscaralexander/pen/dgOYbe?editors=1000). Relevant code below, edited for brevity:

```
loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load('can.dae', function (collada) {
    can = collada.scene;

    can.traverse(function (node) {
        var textureLoader

        if (node.name == 'wrapper') {
            textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

            textureLoader.load('wrapper.png', function (texture) {
                node.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map: texture
                });

                node.material.needsUpdate = true;
            });
        }
    });

    scene.add(can); 
});
```

Illustration of the result. As you can see, the wrapper of the can isn't the red [wrapper.png](https://www.ufomeldpunt.nl/so/wrapper.png) provided, but a solid white fill. I've tried experimenting with mapping and wrapping modes, but to no avail. Any help very much appreciated!

[image]

FYI: I've already ruled out CORS issues.

Comment: Have you done console.logs to make sure your code is getting called?
Hard to debug stuff like this without an example..

Comment: Try loading texture before loading object and then map it

Comment: Can you post the asset + textures and we can take a look?

Comment: NVM saw your codepen. Found what I think is the problem, and answered below..

Answer (score 0):

I added a cube in your loader and gave it that material and it worked.. so the implication is that your can mesh does not have proper UV coordinates assigned to it.. Perhaps it is using an automatic cylindrical mapping in your authoring software which is not exporting it's UVs? What software are you authoring in?

```
            scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1),node.material));
```

https://codepen.io/manthrax/pen/ePBZbZ?editors=1001

Comment: Thanks! The model was created in Cinema4D. The mesh has a UVW Tag ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGXEW.png)), but I'm not sure that's enough? I'm very inexperienced with C4D, unfortunately. I followed a tutorial for creating a UV map and that's how I created the initial texture, but I can't say I fully understand the process.